# Can a conditional formatting rule (marking a value less than any previous value) in a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet column be immune to row insertions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a Microsoft Excel version 2302 (build 16130.20916) spreadsheet, column A contains a heading (text) in row 1 and values (or nothing) in the other rows. A conditional formatting rule marks every value that is less than any previous value.
[image: formatting rule applying to column except first 2 rows]

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any way to lock this rule. Therefore it will get messed up when merging cells or inserting rows. Here is how it will be after inserting 1 row:
[image: formatting rules after inserting a row]

This only gets worse when inserting more rows, until it is cleaned up manually. Thankfully, a formatting rule seems immune to row insertions if the rule applies to a whole column. A formula for such a rule can be tested in the B column. It correctly calculates FALSE or TRUE in each cell:
[image: testing formula for detecting values that should be formatted by the rule]

Unfortunately, the formula does not work in conditional formatting:
[image: formatting rule applied to whole column but not working]

It is possible for a macro to fix the formatting rules and there is probably a trigger that can execute such a macro after each change (such as a row insertion or cell merger or split). But I would like to avoid that because macros are so poorly integrated into Microsoft Excel (it breaks the undo feature).

**Can such a conditional formatting rule be made to work when applied to the whole column? Or is there a better solution?**

The solution should also work if < is changed to <=, to mark any value that is less than or equal to any previous value.

Comment: Convert your data to a Table (also known as a Structured Table or List Object) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clumsy workaround. Instead of using IF or AND, I make separate rules for each of the operands of those functions and stop when a condition is TRUE. Since all rules apply to the whole column, they seem to be immune to row insertions.
[image: clumsy workaround]

Of course, this workaround will break any later, unrelated formatting rules that one may want to use in the A column. Feel free to suggest better solutions.

I switched to this solution to protect the rules from row insertions. Next step is to make a macro that cleans up the rules after cell mergers/splits, thereby sacrificing undo functionality.